# React Native with type script: have to restart the development server everytime i make any changes in code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-ios

I am working in mac os, with react native in type script. I am using gulp to compile the code and create js build. Whenever I make any change in file, app gives error on reloading. I have to rerun npm start and then reload the app. It gives error in the compiled js code, at the very first line where I import a file present inside the project

```
import * as React from "react";
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, View, TextStyle} from "react-native";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";

import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import {reduce} from "./reducers";
import Layout from "./Layout";
```

I get error in the line where i import reducers.

Comment: What does your gulp task look like? It may be hosing the source files and causing the packager to crap out midway through it. Personally, I'm using a technique similar to [this](http://www.reactnative.tools/tutorials/2016/09/20/reactnative-ts/) for RN with TS; my TS compiling task is just a separate npm `tsc -w` task, no need for any complex bundler or task runner.

Comment: It was the issue of watchman. watchman was not installed. Now its working fine.